# How to write a REGEX that captures a string between a string (ie the words between specific words)

Tags: regex, make.com

The Text string below is coming through in the Integromat text parser.  I'm trying to capture the values from a form a user filled out using the built in Integromat Regex text parser.

For example, the test string comes in as (unfortunately the info is not coming through on individual lines):

```
Information First Name:Frank Last Name:McTester Email:mctesterxmas@rya.com
Guest Name:Debby McTester Party RegistrationNumber of Dinner Guests:  2 [http://
```

I need the regex to pull the info `FRANK`, which is between the string `First Name:` and `Last Name:`, so on and so forth.

My current regex works great for emails where these strings are on their own lines.  For example if the email comes in with each string on its own line, then this regex works well.

```regex
First Name:\s*(.*)|Last Name:\s*(.*)|Email:\s*(.*)|Guest Name:\s*(.*)|Number of Dinner Guests:\s*(.*)
```

But when everything is mashed up, I cannot figure out how to use regex to parse the string.

Comment: Assuming `PCRE` is available, how about [this](https://regex101.com/r/R105KH/1).

Comment: Is there really no space before `Number of Dinner Guests`?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately that is the case. There is no space before Number of Dinner Guests.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using alternatives, match the entire line with each field in order.

```
First Name:\s*(.*?)\s+Last Name:\s*(.*?)\s+Email:\s*(.*)|Guest Name:\s*(.*?)Number of Dinner Guests:\s*(.*)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I'm new to regex so your insight is greatly appreciated. Your regex did capture the first and last name, and the email, but due to the line break location, the guest name does not get captured. I thought the | symbol indicates a line break, so that field should be captured, I've tried different symbols without any luck. https://regex101.com/r/Vxt1mm/1

Comment: `|` is for alternatives. `xxx|yyy` matches either `xxx` or `yyy`.

Comment: In your sample data, `First Name`, `Last Name` and `Email` are together on one line, while `Guest Name` and `Number of Dinner Guests` are on the second line.

Answer (score 0):

This was the final solution if anyone else needs it.

```
Transaction Date: *(?<date>\S+)|^Information[^:]*:\s*(?<name>.*)Last Name:\s*(?<lastname>.*)Email:(?<email>.*)Guest\n?Name:(?<guestname>.*)|Dinner Guests:\s*(?<guestcount>\d+)
```

or

```
Transaction Date: *(?<date>[^\s\n]+)|^Information[^:]*:\s*(?<name>.*)Last Name:\s*(?<lastname>.*)Email:(?<email>.*)Guest\n?Name:(?<guestname>.*)|Dinner Guests:\s*(?<guestcount>\d+)
```